# EntityFramework context dispose

Tags: entity-framework

I wrote several Applications which works with entity framework.
I used to work with using clause.
With this clause, i am sure the database connexion is closed properly.

But, in some cases, my Database context object is a field of a class. Its instantiation is in the declaration, and there is no using clause.

I've just discovered that, in this case, Dispose() method is not called. With using clause, Dispose() is called automatically

So my question is: What happens if Dispose() is not called on database context ? The destructor is called so do you think database will be closed by destructor ? Or should i call Dispose() manually on the destructor of the container object like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();

    ....

    ~MyClass()
    {
         ctx.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **must not call** `Dispose` at all. Specially `explicitly`.

When you use  `using` it is an `implicit Dispose()` in a `try-finally` block. Which is fine.But you don't need to do it `explicitly`.

**Why ?**

A `separate` or `explicit` `Dispose` statement `can be missed` when an `exception` occurs `earlier`.So there is no guarantee about the `explicit` `Dispose`.

Here it is from **Rowan Miller [MSFT] :**

> The default behavior of DbContext is that the underlying connection is
>   automatically opened any time is needed and closed when it is no
>   longer needed. E.g. when you execute a query and iterate over query
>   results using “foreach”, the call to IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   will cause the connection to be opened, and when later there are no
>   more results available, “foreach” will take care of calling Dispose on
>   the enumerator, which will close the connection. In a similar way, a
>   call to DbContext.SaveChanges() will open the connection before
>   sending changes to the database and will close it before returning.
>
> Given this default behavior, in many real-world cases it is harmless
>   to leave the context without disposing it and just rely on garbage
>   collection.
>
> That said, there are two main reason our sample code tends to always
>   use “using” or dispose the context in some other way:
>
> 1. The default automatic open/close behavior is relatively easy to override: you can assume control of when the connection is opened and
>      closed by manually opening the connection. Once you start doing this
>      in some part of your code, then forgetting to dipose the context
>      becomes harmful, because you might be leaking open connections.
> 2. DbContext implements IDiposable following the recommended pattern, which includes exposing a virtual protected Dispose method that
>      derived types can override if for example the need to aggregate other
>      unmanaged resources into the lifetime of the context.

You can read more about it here : [**Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects? Nope**](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)

[**Managing DbContext the right way with Entity Framework**](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)

Comment: Just a remark: When i do a try... finally, dispose is not automatically called ? So using do more than try finally

Comment: yes,of course.but it is happening inside the `try,finally block implicitly`. it is different when you use it `explicitly`.That is why it is not good to call `dispose explicitly`.No guarantee.

Comment: Okay thanks and do you know if there is a way to make persistent database connexion with EF ? I am an old school PHP developper and we used to work the persistent connection, maybe shared between multiple http requests in order to increase performance. Is there the same way in ASP.Net MVC C# ?

Comment: When working with `Web applications`, use a `context instance per request`.That is the **best way**.I have put a url about it on my post.please read it for more info.

Comment: @Sampath Looks like you don't make a difference between "don't need to" and "must not" or "is very bad". The only truth in this post is contained in the pasted text from the linked post, i.e. that there is no need to call `DbContext.Dispose` in most of the cases. All other about implicit vs explicit are just your personal opinions. There is nothing wrong to call **any** disposable object `Dispose` method **explicity** as many times as you wish.

Comment: I have given that information according to the OP's context.That means when we consider the `DbContext` scenario.A `separate` or `explicit` `Dispose` statement can be missed when an `exception` occurs earlier.That is why it is Bad.There is no guarantee about that. @IvanStoev

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `using` on your parent class, then make it to implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();

    ....

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ctx.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This way, calling your parent class in a using statement will dispose your context when exiting it.